# Как организовать ветки чтобы можно было отследить разработку отдельных частей приложения?

Tags: c#, контроль-версий

Как организовать ветки чтобы можно было отследить разработку отдельных частей приложения?

Чтобы можно было разрабатывать отдельные блоки и выдавать заказчику поэтапно приложение с ограниченным функционалом.
Или ограничение функционала реализуется не через ветки?

Как сделать чтобы можно было отследить работу по отдельному блоку проекта?
Типа ветка в которой можно отследить: **Book.cs** -> **BooksService.cs** -> **BooksRepository.cs**
Или такое не практикуется?

---

## Пример

**Ссылки между проектами:**

- **BookStore.App**;

  - BookStore.DAL;
  - BookStore.Model;
- **BookStore.AppManager**;

  - BookStore.DAL;
  - BookStore.Model;
- **BookStore.DAL**;
- **BookStore.Model**;

Как я вижу ветки - **Схема-1**.
**Схема-1**:
- master
- DevelopBookStoreApp
- DevelopAppManager
- BookStoreModel
- BookStoreDAL

**Описание работы с ветками:**
- Создаём необходимые сущности в ветке **BookStoreModel**;
- Вливаем **BookStoreModel** в **BookStoreDAL**;
- Создаём необходимый функционал в **BookStoreDAL**;
- Вливаем **BookStoreDAL** в **DevelopBookStoreApp** (или в **DevelopAppManager**);

Или так?
**Схема-2**:
- master;
- DevelopBookStoreApp;
- DevelopAppManager;
- BookStoreDALModel;
- Этап-1;
- Этап-2;
- Этап-3;

---

## Update-1

**Схема-3 веток**:
- master;
- DevelopBookStoreApp;
- DevelopAppManager;
- BookStoreModel;
- BookStoreDALBook;
- BookStoreDALCategory;
- BookStoreDALSeller;
- BookStoreDALDeal;
- BookStoreDALBuyer;
- BookStoreDAL;

**Последовательность действий:**
- ветка **BookStoreModel**. Добавить необходимую сущность(Book, Category, Seller, Deal, Buyer);
- перейти в ветку **BookStoreDALBook** (или BookStoreDALCategory, или Seller, Deal, Buyer);
- влить ветку **BookStoreModel** в ветку **BookStoreDALBook** ;
- в ветке **BookStoreDALBook**  создать операции CRUD. Протестировать;
- перейти в ветку **BookStoreDAL**;
- влить ветку **BookStoreDALBook** в ветку **BookStoreDAL**;
- влить ветку **BookStoreDAL**  в ветку **DevelopBookStoreApp**;

**Update-1. Конец**

---

## Проект для примера.

Допустим имеется приложение: BookStore.App
**Сущности:**
- Book       - Книга;
- Category - Категория;
- Seller      - Продавец;
- Deal        - Сделка;
- Buyer      - Покупатель;

**Этапы разработки:**

- **Этап-1**. Задача Разработать приложение **BookStore.App**: просмотр списка Книг.
  Состав:
  - Book       - Книга;
  - Category - Категория;
  Пользователь может:
  - выполнять Чтение списка Книг;
  - назначать категории на Книгу;
- **Этап-2**. Задача Доработать приложение **BookStore.App**:  добавить условный модуль - Продажи (т.е. не отдельный модуль, а классы в составе основного приложения).
  *Состав:*
  - Seller      - Продавец;
  - Deal        - Сделка;
  - Buyer      - Покупатель;
  *Пользователь может:*
  - выполнять Чтение списка Книг;
  - назначать категории на Книгу;
  - выполнять CRUD со Сделками;
  - выполнять CRUD с Покупателями;
- **Этап-3**. Задача Разработать приложение **BookStore.AppManager**:  приложение для управленца.
  *Состав:*
  - Book       - Книга;
  - Category   - Категория;
  - Seller     - Продавец;
  *Пользователь может:*
  - выполнять CRUD с **Книгами**;
  - выполнять CRUD с **Категориями**;
  - выполнять CRUD с **Продавцами**;
  - Сохранить данные по **Продавцам**, **Категориям**, **Продавцами** в общее хранилище(БД);

**Как я вижу решение:**

- **BookStore.App**;

  - BooksService.cs
  - CategoriesService.cs
  - SellersService.cs
  - DealsService.cs
  - BuyersService.cs
- **BookStore.AppManager**;

  - BooksService.cs
  - CategoriesService.cs
  - SellersService.cs
- **BookStore.DAL**;

  - BooksRepository.cs
  - CategoriesRepository.cs
  - SellersRepository.cs
  - DealsRepository.cs
  - BuyersRepository.cs
- **BookStore.Model**;

  - Book.cs
  - Category.cs
  - Seller.cs
  - Deal.cs
  - Buyer.cs

---

**Ссылки между проектами:**

- **BookStore.App**;

  - BookStore.DAL;
  - BookStore.Model;
- **BookStore.AppManager**;

  - BookStore.DAL;
  - BookStore.Model;
- **BookStore.DAL**;
- **BookStore.Model**;

Comment: Причём здесь git и ветки? Ветки можно организовать различными способами (мы, на пример, используем [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)).

Comment: @XelaNimed Я правильно понял фразу `Под каждую новую функцию нужно выделить собственную ветку`?
См. **Update-1** или(и) **Схема-3 веток**. Или это громоздко и сойду с ума там всё сливать и скокать по веткам? Или нормально?

Comment: Если Вы про git-flow принцип, то в целом - "да".